# Ubuntu Docker Build - facing error during run at ENTRYPOINT "No such file or directory"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a working build that I am trying to dockerise. This is my dockerfile, I added the "pwd" and "ls -l" to see if the build is copied correctly and it is. However when I try to run "docker run " I get the error "No such file or directory. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM <base image>
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo 'List all files'
RUN pwd
RUN ls -l
COPY src/mysolution-linux-amd64 /app/
RUN ls -l
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/mysolution-linux-amd64"]
```

I have tried ENTRYPOINT with both "./mysolution-linux-amd64" and "/app/mysolution-linux-amd64" but both fail when I run.

### Output during Docker build

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.014GB
Step 1/8 : FROM <base image>
 ---> 3ed27f7c19ce
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 1b273ccccd22
Removing intermediate container 1b273ccccd22
 ---> 92560bbb67eb
Step 3/8 : RUN echo 'List all files'
 ---> Running in faddc1b6adfd
List all files
Removing intermediate container faddc1b6adfd
 ---> b7b2f657012e
Step 4/8 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 8354a5a476ac
/app
Removing intermediate container 8354a5a476ac
 ---> 204a625b730b
Step 5/8 : RUN ls -l
 ---> Running in 0d45cf1339d9
total 0
Removing intermediate container 0d45cf1339d9
 ---> 6df6451aef44
Step 6/8 : COPY src/mysolution-linux-amd64 /app/
 ---> 44ac2f066340
Step 7/8 : RUN ls -l
 ---> Running in d17ec6b0c7af
total 11460
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root      11734780 Nov 26 04:25 mysolution-linux-amd64
Removing intermediate container d17ec6b0c7af
 ---> 56a879ef9440
Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT ["/app/mysolution-linux-amd64"]
 ---> Running in 33bea73f14dc
Removing intermediate container 33bea73f14dc
 ---> ef794fe310bc
Successfully built ef794fe310bc
Successfully tagged newtech/mysolution:latest
```

Comment: If you run the container in interactive mode (`docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash <image-name-or-id>`) can you find the file?

Comment: No, I get this error - docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Comment: I guess try using `sh` instead? Maybe the container doesn't have `bash` installed.

Comment: Yes, "sh" worked and I am able to see the file that needs to be triggered at entrypoint.

Comment: If you run specify the file to run in the command line(`docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /app/mysolution-linux-amd64 <image-name-or-id>`), it still fails?

Comment: Yes, it fails. That is the strange part. This is the permission for that file -rwxrwxr-x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249899/discussion-between-dash-and-krishnan-v-s).

Comment: Are you running this on the wrong architecture?  Missing shared-library dependencies?  Starting the container with a volume mount that's hiding the binary?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that but what I see is that the file does exist at the stated location but ENTRYPOINT is saying "No such file or directory". If that is related to some other issue, how do I find out ?

Comment: When I used another base image, it worked fine. David's point was right.